# The order of computing composition of permutation when using cycle notation

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

Given two permutations $p,q$, say $p=(234)$ and $q=(123)$, we can compute the product permutation $pq$ by writing out $pq=(234)(123)$, then turn it into disjoint cycles.

In my understanding, we shall do the latter step in the backward direction: first evaluate on $q$, then on $p$. This is because the product permutation really means the composition of functions. And this gives $pq=(13)(24)$.

However, there are several times that I saw people on the internet doing this in the forward manner, which would give $pq=(12)(34)$.

Could anyone please clarify for me if I'm doing this correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do it the same way you do.  It seems to me that if you compose from left to right instead, you have to read the cycles from right to left.

Comment: It's just a matter of definitions. In highschool, learned it the way you do it ($pq$ is first $q$ then $p$), but my group theory course at university does it the other way ($pq$ is first $p$, then $q$). In the second notation, it's customary to write $n\sigma$ instead of $\sigma(n)$ for the element that $\sigma$ takes $n$ to (which personally I found pretty confusing.)

Answer (score 0):

One can understand this by writing out the tables explicitly. Note that permutation $pq$ is applying $q$ and then applying $p$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{permutation} & \text{acts on} & \text{produces}\\
\hline
pq=(234)(123)&1&3 \\
\hline
pq=(234)(123)&2&4 \\
\hline
pq=(234)(123)&3&1 \\
\hline
pq=(234)(123)&4&2 \\
\hline
\end{array}

The disjoint cycles are now visible:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{permutation} & \text{acts on} & \text{produces}\\
\hline
pq=(13)(24)&1&3 \\
\hline
pq=(13)(24)&2&4 \\
\hline
pq=(13)(24)&3&1 \\
\hline
pq=(13)(24)&4&2 \\
\hline
\end{array}

We will use the table below when told specifically that we apply permutation p and then q,
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{permutation} & \text{acts on} & \text{produces}\\
\hline
qp=(123)(234)&1&2 \\
\hline
qp=(123)(234)&2&1 \\
\hline
qp=(123)(234)&3&4 \\
\hline
qp=(123)(234)&4&3 \\
\hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{permutation} & \text{acts on} & \text{produces}\\
\hline
qp=(12)(34)&1&2 \\
\hline
qp=(12)(34)&2&1 \\
\hline
qp=(12)(34)&3&4 \\
\hline
qp=(12)(34)&4&3 \\
\hline
\end{array}